# What Windows editor has CORRECT EOL whitespace handling?

Tags: windows, text-editor, whitespace

I'm looking for a Windows text editor for programming that handles EOL whitespace CORRECTLY, which for my idea of correct means: Strip all EOL whitespace on save, EXCEPT on lines that I haven't edited. This is to minimise the amount of EOL whitespace evil in my world, but not pollute SCM diff/blame with whitespace-only fixes (I have to deal with old / other people's code).

I have played with TextPad, Notepad++, Kodomo Edit and Programmer's Notepad 2, and found all of them lacking.

Also: I don't get along with vi, and I am unsure about Emacs on Windows.

@Matti Virkkunen: I could mess with diff, but I want to fix the problem, not the symptoms. Fixing diff means all my, others, and server side diff tools need to be fixed, and doesn't fix space/noise/hash change issues in SCM.

Example pet hate using that system: "update" tells me a file has changed. Diff shows no changes.

Comment: Can't you set your diff tool to ignore or de-emphasize whitespace changes?

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but can't you just not add whitespace at the end of lines you add?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, [**Komodo Edit**](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) leaves EOL unchanged, unless you explicitly change that in the settings.

Comment: Tried it - doesn't have the behaviour I'm looking for: It strips whitespace from the end of lines if you hit "return" at the end of them, but not if you make other edits to that line and cursor away.
Also a capital sin, when smart indenting inside a function, blank lines are created with tabs in them.
Setting "strip trailing ws on save" strips ALL trailing ws, not just lines I edited.